# Are Runtime libraries included in Visual Studio 2008 Pro by default?

Tags: visual-studio

Can anyone tell me how to check in visual studio if it has the following libraries included?
The first question I have is are any of these included in the VS by default by installing VS 2008.

These are the libraries:

VC++ Runtime libraries

VC++ Static MT CRT libraries

VC++ Dynamic CRT libraries

ATL MFC Shared Libraries unicode

Can you please suggest me what I need to do, if they are not included in the VC++? Can you provide me with their download links please?

Comment: * last line: Can you please suggest me what I need to do ,if they are not included in the VS 2008. Can you provide me wit their download links please.

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio?  Express/Pro/Team?  Not everything is included in the express edition.

Comment: IIRC, all of these libs are included in vs2008. What is the problem you are having, please?

Comment: The problem is I am getting an error message while building a project . Which says Error                                                                                                                                                               :ReadFromStream(IStream *,VARTYPE,ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream,DWORD)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const int' to 'ATL::ClassesAllowedInStream' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h 6054 common

Comment: So the libs should be there. What's the problem?

Comment: So one of my colleague says that it might be a problem with the include libraries. I am not sure how I need to check if all the C++ include directories are correct. How can I do that. please help.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is a big, long, involved answer. For how long have you been using VS to build projects?

Comment: Is this some kind of stupid question I am asking.

Comment: No, but if  you don't have experience with VS development, then you have some work to do. In any case, look for and include the file atlcom.h and see how it goes.

Comment: That is, see if that inclusion will solve the compile problem.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a linker error; it looks like a compiler error. So, yes, your colleague is right: it might have something to do with #include files, in particular with an #include file that your cpp source failed to #include.

Look for and the include the file atlcom.h and see what the compiler says then.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en)

Be sure to get all updates (windows update or e.g. InstallShield update components etc).
Notably, there has been an important update to ATL Server components which I think (IIRC) is in

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 Update (KB974479)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=239a9a68-211b-4ceb-9c2c-392b5ba5f617)

**Update** and check this one too
[Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 ATL Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=294DE390-3C94-49FB-A014-9A38580E64CB)